# Does the change to the grounding law apply to stumping?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

Does the adjustment to the grounding law - that the bat bouncing up will no longer result in a run out, if you don't change your line - apply to stumpings?

I often see a wicket keeper hesitate, hoping that the batsman will lift his/her foot from behind the crease. Does this still apply, or does the batsman have to move out of his/her crease along the pitch line?

Comment: The change is not to Law 38, *Run out*, it is to Law 30, *Batsman out of his/her ground*.

Answer (score 7):

[Law 30.1.2](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-30-batsman-out-of-hisher-ground/) reads as follows (emphasis added):

> 30.1.2 However, a batsman shall not be considered to be out of his/her ground if, in **running or diving** towards his/her ground and beyond, and having grounded some part of his/her person or bat beyond the popping crease, there is subsequent loss of contact
>
> between the ground and any part of his/her person or bat,
>
> or between the bat and person,
>
> provided that the batsman has continued movement in the same direction.

While this could, in  theory, apply to stumpings, for instance if a batsman was a long way out of his/her crease and dives to get back, it would not apply to simply raising a foot off the ground whilst standing at the wicket, since the Law specifies that the batsman must be "running or diving".